# Freedom method for anonymity

Tags: privacy

In a book I am reading, a system called **Freedom** is mentioned as a means to protect user privacy. Though at some point it mentions that it uses multiple proxies, so even if a node behaves maliciously for the user the attack won't be successful.
From what I have read, Freedom only uses Anonymous Internet Proxies (AISs) so I guess it means them, but how is it possible for a beginning node to use multiple proxies (from what I have found till now Tor and other means use only one). Any ideas?

P.S I could not find freedom as a term so I could not add it in tags.

Comment: Do you have a reference to the book? Or the system? A quick search for "Freedom software" brought only the Freedom app that limits internet access, which is rather the opposite of what you describe here.

Comment: Is that a fictional system? As in, is freedom real or made up by the author?

Comment: I did a search for "chain Anonymous Internet Proxies" and came up with multiple results. Would those results answer your question?

Comment: This book is given to me by my University written in my native langauge so i hope what it says is real. I cannot give more info as thios is why i asked here

Answer (score 1):

You didn't state the age of the book, but this may refer to a no-longer-produced product called Freedom, produced by a Canadian company that was (at the time) called Zero Knowledge Systems.  I was both an early adopter of this product, as well as someone who had engaged in partnership conversations with ZKS, so it was instantly familiar to me.  Here's a link to a technical PDF that lays out the Freedom architecture in some detail:

http://freehaven.net/anonbib/cache/freedom2-arch.pdf

The company ultimately changed its business model after the events of September 11, 2001, and also changed its name to RadialPoint, so Freedom as described in the pdf is no longer available.  There were some innovative security ideas in the architecture, though.